Data structure with DAG
What I am trying to implement query execution scheduler with typescript project.
Here are some requrements.

A data-graph consists of multiple executable-nodes.
A data-graph is initialized with specific parameters.
A executable-node could depend on other executable nodes.
A data-graph is DAG(Directed acyclic graph)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph

And I want to use auto complete with type coercion
Below is my current implementation and the problem is the class is only used by object so each graph and node is singleton.
sample node class decleration
class QueryExecutionNode<T, D> {
    private _meta: IQueryExecutionMeta<T>;
    public readonly dependency: D;

    hydrate(meta) {
        this._meta = meta;
    }
    instantiate(info) {
        this._meta = {...info.meta}
    }

    updateState(
        nextState: QueryExecutionState,
        updateMeta: Partial<IQueryExecutionMeta<T>>,    
    ) {
        ...upate state logic
    }
    generateQueryWithParams(): [string, any[]] {
        return this.queryGenerator(
            this.dependencies,
            this.meta.dbConnectionInfo
        );
    }
}

sample graph decleration
class QueryExecutionGraph<
    I,
    T
> {
  // After load from DB
  hydrate(metadata: IQueryExecutionMeta<any[]>[]): this {
    // Apply metadata
    metadata.forEach((meta) => {
      const foundNode = this.nodes[meta.nodeName];
      if (foundNode == null) {
        throw new Error(
          `Node ${meta.nodeName} not found in graph ${this.graphName}`,
        );
      }
      foundNode.hydrate(meta);
    });

    return this;
  }


  instantiate(
    initialParam: I[] = [],
  ): this {
    // Instantiate
    this.sortEntries(Object.entries(this.nodes)).forEach(
      ([nodeName, node], index) => {
        node.instantiate(
          this.graphName,
          instantiateString,
          nodeName,
          index,
          QueryExecutionState.INITIALLIZED,
          dbConnectionTarget,
          dbConnectionInfo,
        );
      },
    );
    ...set initial state of nodes
}

sample execution node
export interface IcGetTargetPatientCodeNodeResult {
  reception_code: string;
}
export const props: QueryExecutionNodeProps<
  IcGetTargetPatientCodeNodeResult,
  { initialDataNode: QueryExecutionNode<IExecutionGraphV1Params, any> }
> = {
  dependencies: { initialDataNode: ExecutionGraphV1InitialDataNode },
  queryGenerator: (dependencies): [string, any[]] => {
    if (

      dependencies.initialDataNode.data == null ||

      dependencies.initialDataNode.data.length === 0

    ) {

      throw new Error(
        `Initial data is not valid - initialData: ${dependencies.initialDataNode.data}`,
      );
    }
    const initialData = {
      alsoIncludeExamineeCodes:
        dependencies.initialDataNode.data[0].alsoIncludeExamineeCodes,
      finalizedDate: dependencies.initialDataNode.data[0].finalizedDate,
    };
    const qb = new DataSource({ type: 'mssql' })
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .select([
          test as reception_code
      ])
      .from('sample', 'sample')
    return qb.getQueryAndParameters();
  },
  
  resultValidator: (
    data: IcGetTargetPatientCodeNodeResult[] | null,
  ): boolean => {
    const schema: z.ZodType<IcGetTargetPatientCodeNodeResult[]> = z.array(
      z.object({
        reception_code: z.string(),
      }),
    );
    const parseResult = schema.safeParse(data);
    const isParseSuccess = parseResult.success;
    if (!isParseSuccess) {
      console.log(parseResult.error);
    }
    return isParseSuccess;
  },
};

export const cGetTargetPatientCodeNode = new QueryExecutionNode(props);

sample execution graph
export const executionGraphV1 = new QueryExecutionGraph(
  QueryExecutionGraphNames.EXECUTION_GRAPH_V1,
  {
    initialDataNode: executionGraphV1InitialDataNode,
    cGetTargetPatientCodeNode,
    iGetTargetPatientInfoNode,
    ...
  },
);


I want to declare dependency only once, for this case at each node's.
And each dependency should be injected automatically and able to use type coercion at injected method.

I've tried dependency injection but that only works with constructor, and also working with decorator for metadata but it makes very difficult to read code and type coercion.
Any recommendation or advice on new approaches will be very thankful!
